# How to useState of List<int> in Flutter hooks?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-widget, flutter-hooks

I have very simple case of using flutter hooks:

```
class PositionedTiles extends HookWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final counterList = useState<List<int>>([1,2,3,4,5]);
    return Scaffold(
        body: Text("Counter: ${counterList.value}"),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: () => counterList.value.removeAt(0),
              child: const Icon(Icons.sentiment_very_satisfied)),
        );
    );
  }
```

So, after click `floatingActionButton` the printed list (`counterList`) doesn't change. I conclude that rebuild is not invoked.

Why hook doesn't see that the list has been changed?

How to signal that the list (`counterList`) has been changed after `onPressed` invoked in order to rebuild?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To update the state you need to reassign the list.

```dart
onPressed: () {
  counterList.value = [...counterList.value..removeAt(0)];
  log("${counterList.value}");
},
```